# Postfix Hash Database and Email Password Files

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04

I configured Postfix to send email using Gmail, as described in a [Linode documentation](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/configure-postfix-to-send-mail-using-gmail-and-google-apps-on-debian-or-ubuntu/). 
As explained there, I created the `/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd` file and added the SMTP Host, username, and password information:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 username@gmail.com: password
```

Then I created the hash db file for Postfix by running the postmap command:

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd
```

This created the `/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd.db` file.
At this point I sent a test email but unfortunately it was rejected by Gmail.
Less secure apps are already allowed, so I tried to change the password for the Gmail account, as suggested at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44927470).

Now I suppose I have to create new `/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd` and `/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd.db` files.
What is the procedure? Am I expected to delete the old files, create a new `/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd` file and rerun `sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passwd`?

Comment: just rerun postmap. it will recreate the .db file.